# API not displaying data in Swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Currently not getting data from API to display.

Current code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Response: Decodable {
    var content: [Result]
}

struct Result : Decodable {
    var code: String
    var fire: String
    var name: String
    var police: String
    var medical: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var content = [Result]()

    var body: some View {
        List(content, id: \.code) { item in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.name)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text(item.medical)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    func loadData() {
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://emergency-phone-numbers.herokuapp.com/country/gb")!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error { print(error); return }
            do {
                let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
                // we have good data – go back to the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // update our UI
                    self.content = decodedResponse.content
                }
                
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Current error:

2021-01-21 19:21:07.094582+0000 iTunes API[39924:1098972] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "content", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "content", intValue: nil) ("content").", underlyingError: nil))

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the content from `https://emergency-phone-numbers.herokuapp.com/country/gb` is:

```json
{"code":"GB","fire":"999","police":"999","name":"United Kingdom","medical":"999"}
```

The problem is that there's no `content` on the response that you're getting, so the `JSONDecoder` is failing to parse the response. It seems the response you get contains content that fits on `Result`, so if you change your code to parse that, it works fine:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Response: Decodable {
    var content: [Result]
}

struct Result : Decodable {
    var code: String
    var fire: String
    var name: String
    var police: String
    var medical: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var content = [Result]()

    var body: some View {
        List(content, id: \.code) { item in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.name)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text(item.medical)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    func loadData() {
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://emergency-phone-numbers.herokuapp.com/country/gb")!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error { print(error); return }
            do {
                let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data!)
                // we have good data – go back to the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // update our UI
                    self.content = [decodedResponse]
                }
                
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
}
```

I guess, in the end, you probably wanted a collection of `Result`s to fit on the `content`, so you might need to change something on that API of yours to return that collection, then your code would work fine.